# "Gasoline" in Other Languages

Tags: terminology

I speak Russian and the term used for gasoline is "бензин", pronounced like benzene. I've also noticed that in Italian, it can be called "benzina". What's the significance behind this, if any? I think gasoline contains benzene, but that seems like a very minor part of the overall composition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about etymology rather than chemistry.

Comment: I vote not to close it. We chemists might be more suited for answering it than etymologists. On a side note, to make things worse, Russian for benzene is "бензол", pronounced like "benzol", as if it were some sort of alcohol, which is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak about the etymology of the word, since I don't speak any of the languages in question (plus, it it is purely concerned with that, I believe this question is off topic here).

However, if you are interested in the contents of gasoline, I can tell you a little something about them.

Gasoline (or petrol if you're not from North America) is typically a mixture of hydrocarbons with 4 to 12 carbon atoms per molecule. It is a comprises of alkanes, cycloalkanes, alkenes, or in industry parlance parrafin, naphthenes and olefins.

Moreover, as you suspected, it does contain aromatics in general and benzene in particular, and most countries set limits on their content in the fuel. For example, in the EU the benzene content should be under $1\%$ (v/v) for automative grade gasoline$^{[1]}$ Benzene, Toluene, and Xylene ([BTX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTX_(chemistry))) are important petrochemicals, and valuable chemical feedstocks, and most are often recovered during catalytic reforming.

---

1. [EU: Fuels: Diesel and Gasoline](http://transportpolicy.net/index.php?title=EU:_Fuels:_Diesel_and_Gasoline)